# How can I exclude specific folders with a specific year for the crawler in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, glob

I do not quite understand how AWS Glue exclude paths work for the crawler.
I have the following folder structure:

```
s3://hourly/20170101-20170201/
s3://hourly/20180101-20180201/
s3://hourly/20180201-20180301/
s3://hourly/20190701-20190801/
s3://hourly/20190801-20190901/
s3://hourly/20190901-20191001/
s3://hourly/20200101-20200201/
s3://hourly/20200201-20200301/
```

Now I want to exclude all folders that are not from 2018 for example using exclude.

According to the docs:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude

What I can do is to include for example the field *2020* to exclude the folders with the year 2020 from my list.
So what I tried was adding all the years to the exclusion fields: *2017* *2019* and *2020*.

[image: Exclusion muster options]

My results, however, still have the other years in it so apparently this did not work.
I also tried this here *{2017,2019,2020}* which did not work either.

Can someone tell me how I need to use the exclusion pattern to only include folders that have the year 2018 in it? Like only these here and ignore the rest?

```
s3://hourly/20180101-20180201/
s3://hourly/20180201-20180301/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an S3 key prefix pattern, which means the pattern needs to match the prefix (beginning) of the object key. The pattern is not a regular expression that can simply match any substring of the object key.

Assuming the S3 bucket name is not actually `hourly` and the Glue crawler's crawl path is set to the root of the bucket, then the exclude pattern should contain a wildcard (`*`) to match the `hourly` prefix.

```
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20170101-20170201/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20180101-20180201/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20180201-20180301/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20190701-20190801/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20190801-20190901/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20190901-20191001/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20200101-20200201/
s3://<bucket_name>/hourly/20200201-20200301/
```

Exclude Patterns:

```
*/2017*  <-- matches key 'hourly/20170101-20170201/'
*/2019*
*/2020*
```

The exclude pattern is relative to the Glue crawler's crawl path.